# Trying to parse a string that I generate in a batch file into a few values of an XML file

Tags: batch, batch-file, xml, robocopy, batch-rename

I'm trying to create V2 of my little batch file. I only know batch , so I'd prefer to do this if possible instead of powershell but if I have to, I have to.

The app just copies five files that are the same into a directory. Changes the subdirectory to a unique value I generate called CurrentDate.

Now they are asking me if I can take rename the files uniquely before copying, should be easy enough -- where I'm struggling is the five files are referenced in an XML file. So for this to work I need to edit the XML each time to reference the five files with the new unique name "%CurrentDate%.png"

I have attached what a before and after attached. Luckily the source file names are the same across all references and does not change ever. "sample_" Its only on the destination file it creates each time its ran does it need to be unique.

Source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
< Id="sample_Back_-" Type="Value" Style="PRESET" Color="#FFFFFF" XOffset="0" YOffset="0">
    <Foundation FileName="sample_Back_--P.tif"/>
    <White FileName="sample_Back_--W.tif"/>
    <Color FileName="sample_Back_--CMYKRG.tif"/>
    <Preview FileName="sample_Back_-.png"/>
</end>
```

Destination:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
< Id="%SYSTEM_TIME%_Back_-" Type="Value" Style="PRESET" Color="#FFFFFF" XOffset="0" YOffset="0">
    <Foundation FileName="%CurrentDate%_Back_--P.tif"/>
    <White FileName="%CurrentDate%_Back_--W.tif"/>
    <Color FileName="%CurrentDate%_Back_--CMYKRG.tif"/>
    <Preview FileName="%CurrentDate%_Back_-.png"/>
</end>
```

If its relevant here's how I generate the CurrentDate, just a few mkdir and robocopy's follow this

```
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%A in ('date/t') do (
set DateDay=%%A
set DateMonth=%%B
set DateYear=%%C
)

for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%D in ('time/t') do (
set DateTime=%%D
)

set CurrentDate=LOCATION-%DateDay%-%DateMonth%-%DateYear%-%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%
```

Comment: You may want to try asking this over on StackOverflow instead, they're more into the coding side of things than SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

Understand that dealing with .xml files with the bat is possible, but it will involve some things that explain is complicated for my poor / poor English, forgive me... I use Google online translator, if something goes wrong, don't blame me :)

```bat
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0"
set "_local=Rio_de_Janeiro_RJ"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
2>nul del/q /f "%~dp0Q1615046.tmp" >nul

for /f %%i in ('wmic.exe OS Get localdatetime^|findstr \.')do set "_dt=%%~i"
     set "_dt=!_dt:~6,2!-!_dt:~4,2!-!_dt:~0,4!-!_dt:~8,2!.!_dt:~10,2!
    
for /f usebackq^tokens^=*^delims^= %%i in (`type "%~dp0Q1615046.xml"`)do set "_str=%%~i" && (
for %%i in ("<",">","!_dt!")do if not "%%~i"=="!_dt!" (cmd/v/s/c set "_srt=!_str:%%~i=^%%~i!"
     )else set "_str=!_str:sample=%_local%-%%~i!" & echo=!_str!>>"%~dp0Q1615046.tmp")
     
>nul move/y "%~dp0Q1615046.tmp" "%~dp0Q1615046.xml" && endlocal && goto :eof
```

---

- **1.** Enter the folder where the .xml file is, if it is the same as the bat, use **`cd /d "%~dp0"`**, otherwise, replace it with the full path **`cd /d "Drive:\Full\Path\To\xml\Folder`**
- **2.** Part of the code will use the double **`for`** loop, so it is recommended to enable/use expanded variables at run time, enable this with **`Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`**
- **3.** Get your date/time with some predictable and fixed layout using a method that will not change the output by any user settings, region and/or language…

```bat
for /f %%i in ('wmic.exe OS Get localdatetime^|findstr \.')do set "_dt=%%~i"

set "_dt=!_dt:~0,4!-!_dt:~4,2!-!_dt:~6,2!-!_dt:~8,2!.!_dt:~10,2!"
rem ::       %%i: !_dt!       20210108095144.564000-180
rem ::  datetime: !_dt:~0,12! 20210108095144.564000-180
rem ::      year: !_dt:~0,4!  2021
rem ::     month: !_dt:~4,2!      01
rem ::       day: !_dt:~6,2!        08
rem ::      hour: !_dt:~8,2!          09
rem ::    minute: !_dt:~10,2!           51
```

- **Obs.:** Use the command **`wmic.exe OS Get localdatetime`** to get the
  datetime in a fixed and predictable layout output, where no user change, or
  language/region changes that output, and add **`findstr \.`**, to filter the
  line that brings literally (`\`) a (`.`) period.

```bat
rem ::  porting to the layout intended in the question:
rem ::        day:      month:       year:       hour:     minute:
rem ::  !_dt:~6,2!  !_dt:~4,2!  !_dt:~0,4!  !_dt:~8,2! !_dt:~10,2!
rem ::          08         -01       -2021         -09         .51
```

- **4.** Use the bat to create a temporary file where the edits will take place, and at the end of the script this temporary file will be used to overwrite the original .xml

```bat
rem :: Delete if there is any previous execution already omitted possible non-existence error.
2>nul del/q /f "%~dp0Q1615046.tmp" >nul

....
rem :: Use the temporary file already containing the edits to overwrite the existing xml
>nul move/y "%~dp0Q1615046.tmp" "%~dp0Q1615046.xml"
```

**5.** Use a `for` loop to list line by line of your.xml file already defining line in a variable for use in a second loop.

```bat
for /f usebackq^tokens^=*^delims^= %%i in (`type "%~dp0Q1615046.xml"`)do set "_str=%%~i"
```

**6.** Use a `For /F` loop to list line by line of `your.xml` file already defining the current line in a variable for use in a second **`For /F`** loop.

```bat
for /f usebackq^tokens^=*^delims^= %%i in (`type "%~dp0Q1615046.xml"`)do set "_str=%%~i"
```

**7.** Your additional/second **`For /F`** loop will replace the characters that need to be escaped in the **`echo line`** command, this is done line by line,

```bat
for %%i in ("<",">","!_dt!")do apply susbtrings replaces...
```

**8.** Where the line contains **`<, >, sample`** will be replaced respectively by **`^<;, ^>;, Rio_de_Janeiro_RJ-14-01-2021-05.51`** subject to the **`if() else() condition`**

```bat
...("<",">","!_dt!")do if not "%%~i"=="!_dt!" (cmd/v/s/c set "_srt=!_str:%%~i=^%%~i!"
     )else set "_str=!_str:sample=%_local%-%%~i!"
```

**9.** The first loop deals line by line, and the second loop has ordered that the occurrences start from the line **`<`**, end of the line **`>`** and **`sample`** in the middle of the line, and condition an **`if () else ()`** to add the necessary escapes (at the beginning and at the end of the line, and loop makes the replacement of the **`datatime`** (in the middle of the line) the last to occur.

```bat
for /f (line by line) for /f (<, >, datetime_var) in actual line (
    if %%G not equal datetime_var add escaping ) else (
    this is last replace in line, so. echo variable line escapaded > fileTMP.xml)
```

**Obs.:** The replacement of the **`sample`** by the desired string will only occur where the **`sample`** string exists, whether there is no current result in the current line, and immediately this action, this final string with the necessary escaping and replaces will be echoed to the **`xml.tmp`** file:

```bat
for /f usebackq^tokens^=*^delims^= %%i in (`type "%~dp0Q1615046.xml"`)do set "_str=%%~i" && (
for %%i in ("<",">","!_dt!")do if not "%%~i"=="!_dt!" (cmd/v/s/c set "_srt=!_str:%%~i=^%%~i!"
     )else set "_str=!_str:sample=%_local%-%%~i!" & echo=!_str!>>"%~dp0Q1615046.tmp")
```

**10** Finally, after all lines and substitutions have been applied, overwrite the original .xml file with the temporary one created in the execution, using a **`move /y`**...

```
>nul move/y "%~dp0Q1615046.tmp" "%~dp0Q1615046.xml"
```

---

- Some further reading:

  - **[IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**
  - **[set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**
  - **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**
  - **[For /D](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**
  - **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**
  - **[Echo on | off](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**
  - **[Findstr /?](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**
  - **[Redirections in bat file](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**
  - **[Conditional Execution `||` and `&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**
  - **[What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work)**
  - **[Understanding start, 2>nul, cmd, and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**